# C++ why class member cannot be redeclared but normal function can

Tags: c++

```
void say();
void say();  // ok

class Test{
    void say();
    void say(); // error class member cannot be redeclared
};
```

is this because class member function declaration allocates memory so that the compiler doesn't allow redeclaration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont why it is so but the standard forbids it. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.mfct#2. *a member function shall not be redeclared."

Comment: It is because the first two are `extern` references, and you can have as many of those as you like, and the second two aren't.

Comment: Since a class member cannot be redeclared outside the class definition, and all definitions of the class (in different compilation units) must be identical (in terms of the tokens that, collectively, make up the definition) what practical value would there be in declaring a class member more than once in a class definition?

Comment: For me, the question is more *why external function can be redeclared?*. And my answer to that is: *for historical reasons*. C is a old language and originally was not well organized: it was common to declare functions (usually without their argument types) nearly everywhere in the code, and duplicate declaration was common. For compatibility, C++ needed to accept that also, although C++ only features tend to be much more strict.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare things in c++ as many times as you like (as long as they're all the same). You can only define things once.

In the case of class member declarations though you are declaring something you are actually defining the class members and declaring the same member twice isn't allowed. If we use variables rather than functions it's more obvious why the rules exist:

```
extern int a;
extern int a; //  just a redeclaration, that's fine
struct B
{
  int b;
  int b; // not allowed, is this a second member also called b or is it a redeclaration of the existing member?
};
```